# SOAP libraries for iOS application develop in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, soap

I need to develop an iOS application that uses SOAP to send messages to the server.

I've been searching, the results that always comes up are the Sudzc and wsdl2objc and both of them are not what I need. Then I saw csoap, is it a counterpart of ksoap for iOS?

If not, is there any other SOAP libraries for iOS that I can use?

Comment: What really you want?

Comment: Wery stupi colsin as this IS relevant usefull question...  Thi stype of quastions helped me a lot of time... Always closed but always helpfull...

Answer (score 3):

I am in the search of the same thing. Till now I found this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/UsingWebservices/Tasks/Tasks.html

I check it and see if it helps, I am a very beginner for objective-c though

Comment: I see it's for mac so back to searching :)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but try this:

[SOAPEngine](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine)

Comment: That lib is so nice and help ful but It is a licence library .. any dropback of it ?

Comment: Usually ppl try to find free solution over internet a paid one can be found in header of each google search..

Comment: That was clearly not a part of the requirement. But why comment on an answer to a question closed as off-topic? If you can't contribute by suggesting a better alternative, I don't see the point.